# Объединение excel-файлов

Tags: java, excel, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Есть два excel-документа, на каждом по странице(А4) информации. 
Можно ли объединить эти два excel-документа в один программно?

Comment: Есть модули для Питона xlrd и xlwr.

Comment: А еще можно мышкой скопировать и вставить, эт я к общей информации, так как по тегам непонятно и питон предлогают )

Comment: Конечно можно. ИМХО, самый простой способ - встроенными скриптами екселя (VBA). Вот только объединять можно по разному, не знаю что именно Вам требуется.

Comment: Нужна простейшая программа: в консоле, допустим, пишем "7" и он соединяет два определенных excel-файл

Comment: Как вы хотите их соединить?  
Копировать страницы целиком? Или складывать значения ячеек? Или копировать данные с одного документа и вставлять в конец второго?

Comment: в конец первого вставлять начало второго. Так называемое слияние

Answer (score 3):

В интернетах полно информации по данному вопросу, надо только не лениться и гуглить.

- [C++ и Excel](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread6617.html)
- [Как через с++ связаться с excel](http://forum.shelek.ru/index.php/topic,12662.0.html)

и тд и тп.